# Best set-up to navigate the dark web anonymously

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, tails, mac

OK so I'm fairly new but a very fast learner and I investigate everything before I jump and do something. So my questions is this:

What's the best set-up?

I have a Mac and was thinking of just running Tails, since Mac is clean, and Wi-Fi is public.

Now I'm reading so much on Mac vulnerabilities along with Tails own vulnerabilities. Then I see to make sure to use a VPN among other set-ups.

Somebody help me out.
What's the easiest set-up that gives me invisibility?

I have a Mac and other computers and I can learn any OS or program.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser should be sufficient on any platform.

But any answer depends on what kind of attacks you want to protect yourself against. I recommend to read [Assessing Your Risks](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/assessing-your-risks) by the [EFF](https://ssd.eff.org/).

This site also contains a good tutorial on [how to use the Tor Browser](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-use-tor-macos).

Answer (score 0):

> What's the easiest set up that gives me invisibility?

Anonymity online is what Tor is created for, and the Tor Browser is the flagship product of the [Tor Project](https://torproject.org/). However, there are measures to take to make it even more secure:

- Click the Tor button **>** *Security Settings* and set the security level to the safest:
  [image]
- Use [bridge relays](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/en-US/bridges.html). It makes it more difficult for censors to block Tor or identify you.
- Install Tor to a USB drive, take it with you anywhere you wish, and you will be harder to trace. If you want a portable Tor-enabled operating system, then [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) is your best bet.

> Then I see to make sure to use a vpn among other set ups.

You don't really need to combine Tor and a VPN. Look at the following Q & A:
[Can I use a VPN with Tor?](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/teams/CommunityTeam/Support#CanIuseaVPNwithTor)

> I have mac and other computers and I can learn any os or program

Here's a step-by-step guide to using Tor on different operating systems:
[How to Circumvent Internet Censorship with Tor](https://sites.google.com/view/howtos/how-to-circumvent-internet-censorship-with-tor)